# Trying to configure ruby on rails in windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have been trying to configure rails in windows. Ruby has got successfully installed but when i tried to give gem update --system command in my cmd prompt the following happens. MySQL is already installed in my system and is working fine.

```
C:\Ruby187\bin>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.11
Updating RubyGems to 1.8.11
Installing RubyGems 1.8.11
RubyGems 1.8.11 installed

== 1.8.11 / 2011-10-03

* Bug fix:
  * Deprecate was moved to Gem::Deprecate to stop polluting the top-level
    namespace.


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
        C:/Ruby187/bin/gem


C:\Ruby187\bin>
```

please help me in this solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Or what MySQL has to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't see any errors?

Type

```
gem -v
```

and you see your current gem version

Comment: That's not an answer; that's a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

In our team we used to get this problem everytime we `svn up`. We have configured bundle in our application. Here we have a list of gems in a file called `GemFile`. So every time we `svn up` our code we need to `./bundle install` to have all our required gems for this application. This solved our problem.